# rtsp server from uri

Tags: c, rtsp, gstreamer

I'm trying create one pipeline which receives stream from uri, add one textoverlay and makes a new stream.

when i try this:

```
str ="videotestsrc !" 
            "textoverlay text=\"It Works!!!!\" color=4 valign=top halign=right !" 
            "video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! " 
            "x264enc ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 !"
```

it works perfectly, but when i try from uri:

```
str = "uridecodebin uri=http://otp1.rtp.pt:80/liverepeater/smil:rtp1.smil/playlist.m3u8 !" 
            "textoverlay text=\"It Works!!!!\" color=4 valign=top halign=right !" 
            "video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! " 
            "x264enc ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 !"
```

it doesn't work..

Someone  knows why it doesn't work?

My full code:

```
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

static gboolean timeout (GstRTSPServer * server, gboolean ignored){
    GstRTSPSessionPool *pool;
    pool = gst_rtsp_server_get_session_pool (server);
    gst_rtsp_session_pool_cleanup (pool);
    g_object_unref (pool);
    return TRUE;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstRTSPServer *server;
    GstRTSPMediaMapping *mapping;
    GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

    mapping = gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping (server);

    factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();

    gchar *str= "( "
            "uridecodebin uri=http://otp1.rtp.pt:80/liverepeater/smil:rtp1.smil/playlist.m3u8 !"
            "textoverlay text=\"It Works!!!!\" color=4 valign=top halign=right !"
            "video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! "
            "x264enc ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 !"
            ")";
    gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, str);
    gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory (mapping, "/test", factory);
    g_object_unref (mapping);

    if (gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL) == 0)
        goto failed;

    g_timeout_add_seconds (2, (GSourceFunc) timeout, server);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    return 0;

failed:
    {
        g_print ("failed to attach the server\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Regards 
Alex